# Python re.search to regex and extract from each item in a list

Tags: python, list, text-extraction

I have a list of html tags from a Beautiful Soup output.  I want to extract the text within each tag and place into a list (spec_names).

```
li_tags = [<li>Brand: STIHL</li>, <li>Product: Chainsaw</li>,<li>Bar Length: 18 inch</li>, <li>Chain Brake: Yes</li>, <li>Weight: 14 pound</li>, <li>PoweredBy: Gas</li>]
```

I thought this would do it:

```
pattern = r'(?<=\<li\>).+?(?=\:)'
spec_names=[]
for x  in li_tags:
    spec_names.append(re.search(pattern,x))
```

Also thought this would do it:

```
pattern = r'(?<=\<li\>).+?(?=\:)'
spec_names=[]
spec_names= [re.search(pattern,x) for x in li_tags]
```

There is a lot of online help checking to see if each list item is a match, but I am wanting to extract the match from inside each list item.  The end result would have spec_names as :

```
['Brand', 'Product', 'Bar Length', 'Chain Brake', 'Weight', 'Powered By']
```

I am not looking for a function, but procedural steps.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't usually use regex to parse text from `beautifulsoup` tags. Use `.text` property:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<li>Brand: STIHL</li>
<li>Product: Chainsaw</li>
<li>Bar Length: 18 inch</li>
<li>Chain Brake: Yes</li>
<li>Weight: 14 pound</li>
<li>PoweredBy: Gas</li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

li_tags = soup.select("li")

spec_names = [tag.text.split(":")[0] for tag in li_tags]
print(spec_names)
```

Prints:

```
['Brand', 'Product', 'Bar Length', 'Chain Brake', 'Weight', 'PoweredBy']
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrej.  That is what I was looking for.  I need to invesitgate the .text property - you shed new light on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use re.findall:

```
import re

li_tags = ["<li>Brand: STIHL</li>", "<li>Product: Chainsaw</li>", "<li>Bar Length: 18 inch</li>", "<li>Chain Brake: Yes</li>", "<li>Weight: 14 pound</li>", "<li>PoweredBy: Gas</li>"]

pattern = r'(?<=\<li\>).+?(?=\:)'
spec_names = []
for li_tag in li_tags:
    spec_names += re.findall(pattern, li_tag)

print(spec_names)
```

Output:

```
['Brand', 'Product', 'Bar Length', 'Chain Brake', 'Weight', 'PoweredBy']
```

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the simplicity of this.  It works great.